# Hidden element in jsp value passing as href parameter

Tags: jsp

I am using spring,i need to create XML file when i click on a button.
I need to pass the value of a hidden element as parameter in href.

How can i achieve this , any help would be appreciable

snippet of my code am attaching here

```
   <div class="portlet-body no-more-tables" id="testf"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="testID" value="dd"><br/> <div style="margin-left:100px">
      <a style="" href="incident/test/testHref.do?testID=<%=testID%>" id="createReport">     Create Report </a> 
    </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: snippet of my code am attaching here

                                                                  <div class="portlet-body no-more-tables" id="testf">
 <input type="hidden" id="testID" value="dd"><br/>

    <div style="margin-left:100px">
     <a style="" href="incident/test/testHref.do?testID=<%=testID%>" id="createReport">
     Create Report
    </a>
 </div>

</div>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the html attribute `name` to  the hidden parameter ,so that you will get the value in the request

```
<input type="hidden" name="testID" id="testID" value="dd"><br/> <div style="margin-left:100px">
```

And `testID` should be Java variable to embed inside the URL as you have used the scriptlets.
so you cant pass it in the `get` request. Instead use `POST` method to get the variable available in the request.

is the trivial way to hardcode the elements in the url.

You can also assign the values to the variable `testID` using scriptlets,

```
<% String testID="dd" ; %>
```

so that it will available when you try to pass like ,

```
<a style="" href="incident/test/testHref.do?testID=dd" id="createReport">Create Report </a>
```

As scriptlets are not advised over the decades , can be replaced with `jstl` ,

```
<c:set var="testID" value="dd" />
```

see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: @ san krish , thank u so much for your kind reply,but my hidden variable is not static,that variable value will change dynamically,so cannot pass  as this href="incident/test/testHref.do?testID=dd", here "dd" i have put as an example.i need to pass current value of hidden vairable

Comment: If you hidden variable in dyanamic (available in the request) . you can do `<c:set var="testID" value="${HiddenValueName}" />` . so that you will have the value in the varible `testID`

Comment: why am using hidden input element instead of <c:set> variable, that value updates as per the click of another button ,there is no server request,its only jquery function,so how can I  dynamically update jstl variable,i need the hidden input element current value when call href each time